# How to convert a user input that is a string into a float? For example, A+ = 4.33

Tags: python

I'm new to Python (5 days or 16 hours in), but I'm enjoying messing around with unknown concepts.

I am trying to create a GPA calculator where the user inputs could range from "A+" to "F". Each letter grade would have a float attached to it, for example `"A" = 4.00`

The GPA will be the sum of the floats divided by classes taken.

I tried assigning data to the = sign but cannot figure out how to make a str(), whether it be A+,C-,D+, etc., equal to its float equivalent.

I searched for a solution here, but most people suggest adding float(). That's not what I need help with. I know how to convert "43" into 43. What I want is to make a string like "A+" into a float like 4.33.

I hope all of this makes sense. I really appreciate the time you take to help me figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as @SilvioMayolo already mentioned, using a `std::map` or `dict` greatly help your task being finished. Define a dictionary as below (I'm sure that you've learnt dictionaries in your 5-days-course, aren't you? If you don't, comment me):

```py
GRADINGS = {
    "A+": 4.33,
    "A": 4.0,
    "A-": 3.66,  # Change it into what you like
    "B+": 3.33,
    "B": 3.0,
    "B-": 2.66,
    "C+": 2.33,
    "C": 2.0,
    "C-": 1.66,
    "D+": 1.33,
    "D": 1.0,
    "D-": 0.66,
    #etc. Modify as you like.
}
```

To access it, simple, use the index operator `[idx]`.

```py
try:
    grade = str(input("Enter a grade")).lower()
    print("A+ grade is equal to", GRADINGS[grade])
except KeyError:
    print("The grade you entered is not consisted in the index")
```

Or, if you don't want troublesome exception handling, use Python's built-in `dict.get` method.

```py
grade = "Y+" # Obviously it doesn't exist
print(GRADINGS.get(grade), 0.0) # If KeyError, return 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary for this

```py
grade_values = {'A': 4.0, 'B': 3.0, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 1.0, 'F': 0.0}

# example student grades
student_grades = ('A', 'B')
gpa = 0.0
for grade in student_grades:
    gpa += grade_values[grade]
    
>>> results / len(user_gpa)
Out[1]: 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need a dictionary.

```
LETTER_GRADES = {
  "A+": 4.33,
  "A": 4.0,
  "B": 3.0,
  "C": 2.0,
  "D": 1.0,
  "F": 0.0,
}
```

Now, if we have a letter grade stored in a variable `my_grade`, we can access its floating-point GPA value as `LETTER_GRADES[my_grade]`. This will throw a `KeyError` if the letter grade is not a key in the dictionary. If you're not sure whether the input is valid, you can supply a default value with `.get`.

```
my_grade = ...
my_gpa = LETTER_GRADES[my_grade] # Throws KeyError on bad input
my_gpa = LETTER_GRADES.get(my_grade, 0.0) # Defaults to 0.0 on bad input
```

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers here, but it makes sense to put it in a function.

I used a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to get the sum of the grades. Then I divided that by the total number of grades to get the GPA.

One can either use a long if-else statement to check the values, or, use a dictionary to map the grades to a value (ie. A+ -> 4).

It makes more sense to use a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) because it is more concise and much easier to add values (say you wanted to add + or - values for each grade, like B+ or B-).

Using a dictionary, one can use the `dict[key]` syntax, or, to avoid `keyErrors`, use the `.get` method with a default value when no key is found.

```py
# grade values using a dictionary 
grade_values = {
  "A+": 4.33,
  "A": 4.0,
  "B": 3.0,
  "C": 2.0,
  "D": 1.0,
  "F": 0.0,
}

def get_student_gpa(student_grades):
    # list comp that gets the sum of 
    # student grades 
    gpa_sum = sum(grade_values.get(grade, 0.0) 
                  for grade in student_grades)
    # divide gpa_sum by number of grades
    gpa = gpa_sum / len(student_grades)
    return gpa
print(
    get_student_gpa(["A", "A", "B", "A"])
    # 3.75
)
```